# Html Video error in Microsoft edge browser

Tags: video, browser, html5-video, microsoft-edge

My application having multiple videos and images as popups in big screen running in Microsoft edge with mutitouch.but after multuple clicks the video screen become black screen showing sometime decode error and file format not support error .couldnt find the right solution.please help. Is there any other option to run videos without getting errors.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Our concept is through popover , so if u click popover the video will play. The exact scenario where we are getting problem is multiple times if u click the popover the video shows an error like file is not supported to this format. And if we are doing normal html is working fine, but our application is based upon .net project so we are passing ajax call to get the data in JSON format. In this scenario were are getting the error as file type is not supported if we are clicking multiple times, so plz help us how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have several questions.

You had mentioned that You are using a touch screen. So did you wrote any code for multi touch? that may affect the video?

I suggest you to try your site with normal screen and check whether same issue occur or not.

I also suggest you to debug your site with Visual Studio and check which error it produce on which part. It can help us to narrow down the issue.

Further, Try to update the Windows with latest updates. so any Edge related update also get installed.

It will be better, If you post a screen shot of the issue and sample code to produce the issue.

We will try to make a test with that code and try to find the solution for that.

Regards

Deepak